# rank and determinant of system of quadratic equations

Tags: determinant, quadratics, matrix-rank

We have the notion of rank and determinant defined for linear system of equations. 
is the same defined for quadratic system of equations?

Foe eg:
I have system of quadratic equations. the matrix part of this is defined some thing like this as:
$a_{00}x_1^{2}+a_{01}x_1x_2+a_{02}x_2^{2}= c1$

$a_{10}x_1^{2}+a_{11}x_1x_2+a_{12}x_2^{2}=c2$

$a_{00}x_1^{2}+a_{01}x_1x_2+a_{02}x_2^{2}=c_3$

in the above 
can I find the determinant of matrix  $A=(a_{ij})\text{ and rank of }A=(a_{ij})$.

---

Equivalently, how do we conclude the system of quadratic equation is solvable or not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly want $x_1^2$ and $x_2^2$ to be non-negative.  Otherwise treat the system as a linear one with variables $z_1=x_1^2$, $z_2=x_1x_2$ and $z_3=x_2^2$ and check if $z_2^2=z_1z_3$.

Comment: thank you. i was thinking in same lines. But was wondering, in the new variable set there are 3 unknowns.

Comment: if in the above system of equations, if  there are terms $x_1$ and $x_2$, is it still  possible to solve

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.